# Wix : Is there a way to clear a property based on checkbox event

Tags: wix3

I have two text Controls on my Wix custom dialog and i want to clear the property so that the text value is cleared when my checkbox is unchecked.Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try with <SetProperty Id="PROPERTY_BIND_TO_TXT" Value="" After="InstallValidate" Sequence="execute"/>, changing the apropiate values.

Comment: I want to clear the text field when i uncheck a checkbox.

Comment: That's what that markup is supposed to do, it sets Value property to empty string. Sorry, I'm too busy to go deeper :-(